# asp.net mvc - category/1 to category/fruit... right approach?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

suppose I have 3 categories 1, 2, 3 named fruit, vegetable and grain.

Right now I have domain.com/category/1 which would take me to fruit's page and so on...

Now I would like to domain.com/category/fruit to take me to fruit's page because that looks nicer and categories are very few like 3 or 4 max... so I don't plan on looking at database to see what categoryid refers to what name.

Should I just use a global enum/array? (any examples?)

It just seemed weird, because I have a dropdown that lists all the categories and I look at the selected integer value of the category (assume 1) and pass it on to Category ActionResult and then the actionresult looks at "fruit" and then converts it back to 1... so I am going back and forth just so that URL would look nice, which makes me wonder if I
should do some kind of URL routing in global.asax for this?

Or maybe I should use web.config to declare fruit = 1 and so on...?

There are several ways to do this I guess, but I want to know the most efficient way.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you expose the number 1 to your visiors, and then stop selling fruit in the future, you might have wasted the number 1. If you keep your category numbers to yourself, you have more flexibility.

Comment: and that's exactly what i wanna do. hide categoryid from user... what's the best approach?

Comment: I'd go with @rball but remove the numerical IDs from the routes. You can just store your numerical mappings (fruit ==> 1 etc) somewhere; preferably in your database and cache them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910249/asp-net-mvc-category-1-to-category-fruit-right-approach/3910285#3910285

Answer (score 0):

I do something like:

```
/category/1/fruit
/category/2/vegetable

{action}/{id}/{*extra}
```

You can do it your way, but then you have to do it just like you're saying.  Probably would want to index the field if you're doing a db lookup.

With keeping the id value in there you don't have to index the field, or do the weird lookup.  The only thing you lose is for people to guess your other category names and type them in manually.  The only person that is really going to care about that is you.

If you really don't want the number and don't want to deal with a database, just create a Hashtable convert the "id" to a value:

```
var categories = new Hashtable();
categories.Add("fruit", 1);
categories.Add("vegetable", 2);
```

Then use fruits[id] to get your number back.

Comment: "I don't plan on looking at database to see what categoryid refers to what name", according to the question.

Comment: I guess change db lookup to switch statement.  :)  I also said "if you're doing a db lookup".

Comment: but you didn't mention where I should store this hashtable...?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to convert the string (`categoryName`) back to an int (`categoryId`)?  Why not just use the string to get the data you need:

Service Call:

```
Data GetDataByCategoryName(string categoryName)
{
   return repository.GetSingle(x => x.CategoryName == categoryName);
}
```